# java arraylist question where is wrong with my code

Tags: java, arraylist

Question 1. (Arrays.java) Write a program that prompts the user to enter in an integer number representing the number of elements (between 2 and 12, use a while loop for input validation) in an arraylist.  Create the appropriately-sized array list and prompt the user to enter in values for each element using a for loop. When the array is full, display the following:

- The values from the array on a single line (comma separated).
- The values from the array on a single line (comma separated) in
  reverse order.
- The values from the array that have odd numbered values.
- The values from the array that have odd numbered indexes. Do not use
  an if statement here.
- The maximum from the array and the position (index) where it occurs.

here is my code. not sure where goes wrong the for loop doesn't run

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class a5q2{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a number 2 to 12");
            num = keyb.nextInt();

        } while(num<2||num>12);

        ArrayList<Integer>list= new ArrayList<Integer>(num);

        //user input
        for(int i =0;i<list.size();i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a Value(list): ");
            int value=keyb.nextInt();
            list.add(value);
        }

        //display list
        System.out.println(list);
        //reverse order
        for(int i =list.size() - 1;i>=0;i--) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i)+",");
        }

        //all odd value


        for(int i =0;i<list.size();i++) {
            if(list.get(i)%2==1)
            System.out.println(list.get(i)+",");
        }

        //odd indices


        for(int i =0;i<list.size();i+=2) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i)+",");
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Try to be more specific in your question than "the for loop doesn't work".  What about it doesn't work?

Comment: all the for loop doesn't run

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the constructor [`public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-):

> Constructs **an empty list** with the specified initial capacity.

(Emphasis mine)

So your loop:

```
for(int i =0;i<list.size();i++){
    System.out.println("Enter a Value(list): ");
    int value=keyb.nextInt();
    list.add(value);
}
```

Will never execute as the size is zero.

You can test this by printing out the size before the loop:

```
System.out.println(list.size());
```

---

To fix this, simply loop until `num`:

```
for(int i =0;i<num;i++){
    System.out.println("Enter a Value(list): ");
    int value=keyb.nextInt();
    list.add(value);
}
```

Comment: but I still need user input to decide the array list size. how exactly can I do that?thanks.

Comment: @JiliangYu Look at the last part of my answer. Loop until `num` instead of `list.size()`

Comment: just tried, all the loop still does not running cause the size is still 0

Comment: @JiliangYu You are still looping until `size()`. Loop while `i < num`. Look at the last part of my answer to see what you need to be doing.